# SQL OVER clause substitution or Visual Studio setting change

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a SQL query that uses an `OVER(PARTITION BY ParamName)` clause.

Here is the whole query:

```
SELECT 
   Products.SerialNumber, Products.StationID, 
   COUNT(Tests.ParamName) OVER (PARTITION BY Tests.ParamName) AS ParamNameCount, 
   Tests.ParamName, Tests.ParamValue, Tests.LSL, Tests.USL, Tests.ParamUnits
FROM          
   Tests 
INNER JOIN 
   Products ON Tests.P_Idx = Products.P_idx
WHERE      
   (Products.ProductID = @ProductID) AND (Products.TestID = 1) 
   AND (Tests.ParamState = 0) AND (Tests.ParamName <> 'UUT Test State')
   AND (Tests.ParamName <> 'Total Test Time')
   AND (Products.TestDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate)))
GROUP BY 
   Products.StationID, Products.SerialNumber, Tests.ParamName, Tests.ParamValue, 
   Tests.LSL, Tests.USL, Tests.ParamUnits
ORDER BY 
   ParamNameCount DESC, Products.StationID, Products.SerialNumber
```

This query works fine if I use it on the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but the Query Designer GUI on Visual Studio 2010 seems that doesn't supports the `OVER` clause because I get an error that says

> The OVER construct or statement is not supported

I did find one solution online which is to create a store procedure but this solution doesn't work for me since I'm using Crystal Reports which uses the XSD file generated by the Query Designer GUI of Visual Studio 2010.

So I'm wondering if I can change my query to not use the `OVER` clause or if there is a setting or something that I can change on Visual Studio 2010 so the Query Designer GUI allows me to use the `OVER` clause.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure how to over come the issue you are having other than to say that you may have progressed beyond the point of the Query Designer training wheels. You might want to start simply writing your queries using Management Studio as that offers the ability to create much more sophisticated queries than any designer can handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help someone... So I found a way to do it with this very long query:

```
SELECT     tmp5.SerialNumber, tmp5.StationID, tmp4.ParamCount, tmp4.ParamName, tmp5.ParamValue, tmp5.LSL, tmp5.USL, tmp5.ParamUnits, 
                  tmp5.TestDate
FROM         (SELECT     COUNT(ParamName) AS ParamCount, ParamName
                   FROM          (SELECT     Tests.T_Idx, Products.SerialNumber, Products.StationID, Tests.ParamName, Tests.ParamValue, Tests.LSL, Tests.USL, 
                                                                  Tests.ParamUnits, Products.TestDate
                                           FROM          Tests INNER JOIN
                                                                  Products ON Tests.P_Idx = Products.P_idx
                                           WHERE      (Products.ProductID = @ProductID) AND (Products.TestID = 1) AND (Tests.ParamState = 0) AND 
                                                                  (Tests.ParamName <> 'UUT Test State') AND (Tests.ParamName <> 'Total Test Time') AND (Products.TestDate BETWEEN 
                                                                  @StartDate AND DATEADD(second, - 1, DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate))) AND (Tests.T_Idx IN
                                                                      (SELECT     MIN(Tests_3.T_Idx) AS TestIdx
                                                                        FROM          Tests AS Tests_3 INNER JOIN
                                                                                               Products AS Products_3 ON Tests_3.P_Idx = Products_3.P_idx
                                                                        WHERE      (Products_3.ProductID = @ProductID) AND (Products_3.TestID = 1) AND (Tests_3.ParamState = 0) AND 
                                                                                               (Tests_3.ParamName <> 'UUT Test State') AND (Tests_3.ParamName <> 'Total Test Time') AND 
                                                                                               (Products_3.TestDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND DATEADD(second, - 1, DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate)))
                                                                        GROUP BY Products_3.SerialNumber))) AS tmp3
                   GROUP BY ParamName) AS tmp4 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      (SELECT     MIN(Tests_2.T_Idx) AS TestIdx, Products_2.SerialNumber, Products_2.StationID, Tests_2.ParamName, Tests_2.ParamValue, 
                                               Tests_2.LSL, Tests_2.USL, Tests_2.ParamUnits, Products_2.TestDate
                        FROM          Tests AS Tests_2 INNER JOIN
                                               Products AS Products_2 ON Tests_2.P_Idx = Products_2.P_idx
                        WHERE      (Products_2.ProductID = @ProductID) AND (Products_2.TestID = 1) AND (Tests_2.ParamState = 0) AND 
                                               (Tests_2.ParamName <> 'UUT Test State') AND (Tests_2.ParamName <> 'Total Test Time') AND (Products_2.TestDate BETWEEN 
                                               @StartDate AND DATEADD(second, - 1, DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate))) AND (Tests_2.T_Idx IN
                                                   (SELECT     MIN(Tests_1.T_Idx) AS TestIdx
                                                     FROM          Tests AS Tests_1 INNER JOIN
                                                                            Products AS Products_1 ON Tests_1.P_Idx = Products_1.P_idx
                                                     WHERE      (Products_1.ProductID = @ProductID) AND (Products_1.TestID = 1) AND (Tests_1.ParamState = 0) AND 
                                                                            (Tests_1.ParamName <> 'UUT Test State') AND (Tests_1.ParamName <> 'Total Test Time') AND 
                                                                            (Products_1.TestDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND DATEADD(second, - 1, DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate)))
                                                     GROUP BY Products_1.SerialNumber))
                        GROUP BY Products_2.SerialNumber, Products_2.StationID, Tests_2.ParamName, Tests_2.ParamValue, Tests_2.LSL, Tests_2.USL, 
                                               Tests_2.ParamUnits, Products_2.TestDate) AS tmp5 ON tmp4.ParamName = tmp5.ParamName
ORDER BY tmp4.ParamCount DESC
```